# Vehicle Loan Calculator - Having trouble with my program outputting the correct values

Tags: c#, calculator, amortization

I have been trying to get my amortization calculator to work however the ending payment balance does not end on 0 and my code does not output the correct values and I am stuck after doing some googling for a couple hours. I believe my issue is underneath the comment "Listbox Loop." Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Allows for the hotkeys to be used even when out of focus from main form
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void MainForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Adds hotkeys; Enter = Calculate, Escape = Exit
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            calculateButton.PerformClick();
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
        {
            exitButton.PerformClick();
        }
    }

    private void rebateCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enables & Disables rebate textbox based on rebate checkbox
        if (rebateCheck.Checked == true)
        {
            rebateBox.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rebateBox.Clear();
            rebateBox.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    /* Selects data inside of the textbox when tabbing or clicking into it */
    private void loanAmountBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loanAmountBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void loanAmountBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loanAmountBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void annualAPRBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        annualAPRBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void annualAPRBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        annualAPRBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void rebateBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rebateBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void rebateBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rebateBox.SelectAll();
    }

    /* Clears the list box when text is changed on any of the input boxes */
    private void loanAmountBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loanListBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void annualAPRBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loanListBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void rebateBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loanListBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    /* Only allows digits, periods, and control keys to be entered into textboxes */
    private void loanAmountBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void annualAPRBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void rebateBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Asks the user if they are sure they want to exit
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); ;

        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            this.Close();
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declaring all variables
        int monthsCounter;
        double loan;
        double rate;
        double rebate;
        double principal;
        double balance;
        int months = 0;
        double principalPayment = 0;
        double pmt = 0;
        double interest = 0;
        double totalInterest = 0;
        double totalPrincipal = 0;
        double totalPayment = 0;
        double monthlyRate;

        try
        {
            // Parse data from textboxes
            double.TryParse(loanAmountBox.Text, out loan);
            double.TryParse(annualAPRBox.Text, out rate);
            double.TryParse(rebateBox.Text, out rebate);

            // Check which loan month radio button is selected
            if (loan6Months.Checked)
            {
                months = 6;
            }
            else if (loan12Months.Checked)
            {
                months = 12;
            }
            else if (loan18Months.Checked)
            {
                months = 18;
            }
            else if (loans24Months.Checked)
                months = 24;

            // Validates if the Loan Amount textbox is blank and if so, throws an error message pop up
            if (loan == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a loan value.", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                loanAmountBox.Focus();
                loanAmountBox.SelectAll();
            }
            else if (rate == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter/select an APR value.", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                annualAPRBox.Focus();
                annualAPRBox.SelectAll();
            }

            rate = (rate / 100) / 12;
            loan = loan - rebate;


            // Listbox loop
            for (monthsCounter = 1; monthsCounter <= months; monthsCounter = monthsCounter + 1)
            {
                // Add to total variables
                totalInterest += interest;
                totalPrincipal += principalPayment;
                totalPayment += pmt;

                // Calculate the principal payment


                interest = loan * rate;
                principalPayment = (loan * rate * Math.Pow(1 + rate, months)) / (Math.Pow(1 + rate, months) - 1);
                pmt = principalPayment + interest;
                loan = loan - principalPayment;



                // Output data to listbox
                loanListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}{1,12}{2,12}{3,12}{4,12}", monthsCounter, interest.ToString("N2"), principalPayment.ToString("N2"), pmt.ToString("N2"), loan.ToString("N2")));
            }

            loanListBox.Items.Add("");
            loanListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}{1,12}{2,12}{3,12}", "Total", totalInterest.ToString("N2"), totalPrincipal.ToString("N2"), totalPayment.ToString("N2")));
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my output looks like when running the program:
[image: My program]

However, the output is supposed to be this:
[image: Correct output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you're using for amortization is correct, it's what you do after this that is giving you the wrong result. `principalPayment` is the total payment which **includes** interest. You should probably rename this to `totalPayment` because the name is misleading. If you know the total payment amount, and you know the interest. How are you going to get the principal amount?

```
Interest + Principal = Total Payment
```

**Update:**
Keep in mind that the loan value used in the amortization formula is not changed--the original loan amount is used for all calculations.

Any time you see "???", it means that you need to fill in the code.

You may consider adding a variable:

```
double originalLoanAmount = 0;
```

Then put the loan amount into `originalLoanAmount`.

```
double.TryParse(loanAmountBox.Text, out originalLoanAmount);
```

Set initial values before the "for" loop:

```
originalLoanAmount = ???
balance = ???
```

How do you calculate the interest?

```
interest = ???
```

Calculate total payment: (original loan amount doesn't change)

```
pmt = (originalLoanAmount * rate * Math.Pow(1 + rate, months)) / (Math.Pow(1 + rate, months) - 1);
```

What's the principalPayment?

```
principalPayment = ???
```

What's the new balance?

```
balance = ???
```